# Rails assets:precompile is using wrong bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile, bundler

I recently updated my dockerized rails app (5.0 -> 5.2) and am now using Bundler 2.

I've added `RUN gem install bundler` to my `Dockerfile` to ensure I have Bundler 2 installed. My `RUN bundle install` step runs fine, but when I get to the asset precompile step it seems to start using Bundler 1 again:

```
Step 12/17 : RUN rails assets:precompile --trace
 ---> Running in facccf7d562c
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
```

**1. Why is the asset precompile even using bundler?**

**2. How can I force it to user Bundler 2?**

Here is the snippet of my Dockerfile that fails (on the last step):

```
RUN gem install bundler

RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install
RUN rails assets:precompile --trace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been a bug in `Ruby 2.4.0` upgrading to `2.4.5` fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to force Bundler to manage the dependencies:

```
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

Where that ensures the Gem environment is locked in as per the `Gemfile`.

Rails generally tries to get this working for you, but there are occasions when it can't quite get things in sync and the behaviour you're seeing manifests.

Comment: hmm im getting the same error with adding `bundle exec`

Comment: Try `RUN bundle -v` to see if the correct version of bundler is showing up.

Comment: yup `Bundler version 2.0.1`

Comment: Is it possible that for some reason your `Gemfile.lock` specifies an older version of Bundler?

Comment: Nope it specifies 2.0.1

Comment: Is this something you can reproduce on a scratch Rails project? What's interesting is there's an older version of Bundler there, so you may want to `gem  cleanup` after installing the new version, or pre-emptively remove `bundler` first, then install the new one.

Comment: gem cleanup didn't work. I just tried a brand new rails project and got the same error. Im at a loss here.

Comment: You need to remove that Bundler version somehow. `gem uninstall` is a place to start.

Comment: Yup im lost: `RUN gem uninstall bundler --version 1.14.6` -> `bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME`

Comment: That's really strange. Does this happen on other container bases? You might want to experiment and use a different one. I've had really good luck with the [Passenger Rails Containers](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker).

Comment: Ill try another base. Right now im using Ruby2.4.0 as the base. I think ill try linux as the base and then install via RVM

Comment: There's a number of pre-built Ruby + Linux containers that are a good foundation to start with. I've built my own using RVM before, an adaptation of the Ansible infrastructure I had on hand, but there's usually better-maintained containers like those Passenger ones to work with.

Comment: Seems to have been a bug in Ruby 2.4.0 upgrading to 2.4.5 fixed this issue.